# How to retrieve the first 10 childs sorted by value inside the child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have Data that looks like this:

[image]

I want to retrieve only the first 10 users but they should be sorted by key: rank.

This is how i tried to do this, but in this case the response is not sorted , it's just returning me the first 10 users.

How can i get the 10 users with the highest rank?

```
export const leaderBoardUsers = () => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        const leaders = await database().ref(firebaseRefs.USERS_REF).orderByChild('rank').limitToFirst(10).once('value');
        if (leaders.exists()) {
            const data = leaders.val();
            const leadersData = Object.keys(data).map(key => ({...data[key], id: key}));
            resolve(leadersData);
        }else {
            console.log('NOTHING EXIST')
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        reject(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: In addition to Giavanni's fix, you should also not use `Object.keys` but loop over the results with `leaders.forEach`.

Comment: Thank your for the tip @Frank van Puffelen,  Can you explain please ?

Comment: The order of the keys in a JSON object is undefined/not guaranteed, but most JSON engines put the keys in lexicographical order. This means you'll lose the order that you requested when you do `leaders.val()`. Using the built-in `leaders.forEach()` ensures the child nodes are iterated in the order in which you queried them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rank` is a key nested into `userDetails` so you should write:

```
const leaders = await database().ref(firebaseRefs.USERS_REF).orderByChild('userDetails/rank').limitToFirst(10).once('value');
```

So you have to pass `userDetails/rank` to `orderByChild` and not simply `rank`.